# cram-intermediate-tutorial can't find the package

Tags: ros, cram

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following this tutorial http://cram-system.org/tutorials/intermediate/moveit

It says you can download the cram-intermediate-tutorial package from https://github.com/cram-code/cram_tutorials. I can't find that package.

Please could someone guide on where I can find this package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211202/cram-intermediate-tutorial-can%27t-find-the-package/) by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2015-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial code is on a different branch that hasn't been merged in yet. This tutorial is very new and is work in progress. The current pull request is here but it hasn't been reviewed yet: https://github.com/cram-code/cram_tutorials/pull/8

---

Originally posted by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) with karma: 311 on 2015-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1